# Xaml how to make a condition

Tags: sql, xaml

Hi Guys i have a problems

Well, I have a sql command that extracts the number of days remaining until the end of the order. Below is the code in XAML and the problem is that there is no idea how to do that e.g. if the number of days is greater than 5 then color green etc? It's about making a condition. I am a beginner and I am asking for some thought. Regards.

XAML CODE

```
<DataTemplate xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:user="clr-namespace:Okna.Documents.Views.User;assembly=Okna.Documents">
  <Grid
    x:Name="grid">
    <TextBlock
      Margin="3,2"
      Text="{Binding RowData.Row.ud_pozostalo_dni2}" />
  </Grid>
  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger
      Binding="{Binding RowData.Row.ud_pozostalo_dni2}"
      Value="8">
      <Setter
        TargetName="grid"
        Property="Background"
        Value="Green" />
    </DataTrigger>
  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

SQL `select datediff(day,getdate(), o.realizacja)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a value converter for this.
An example converter can be:

```
public class CellColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int val = (int)value;
        if (val > 5)
        {
            return Brushes.Green;
        }
        return Brushes.Transparent;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And in your XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:CellColorConverter x:Key="CellColorConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>


<Grid x:Name="grid">
<TextBlock
  Margin="3,2"
  Text="{Binding RowData.Row.ud_pozostalo_dni2}" Background="{Binding RowData.Row.ud_pozostalo_dni2,Converter={StaticResource CellColorConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```